# Bluetooth doesn't connect

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have two apps: one acting as a Server in a device with Android 7.1.2 (a camera) ,and another one acting as Client in Android 7.0. (Samsung Galaxy S7). I did the pairing so they both appear in each other discovery method.

Client does:

```
...
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mmSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
...
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

try {
    mmSocket.connect();
} catch (IOException connectException) {
    connectException.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

And Server does:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mmServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("name",UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
...

BluetoothSocket socket = null;
boolean connected = false;
// Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned.
while (true) {
    if(!connected) {
        try {
            MyLog.d(TAG, "accepting");
            socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            MyLog.e(TAG, "Socket's accept() method failed");
            break;
        }
    }
...
}
```

Everything works fine when I test my apps in two normal Android phones, and when I use my server in a phone and my camera as a client.

But if I try to run the server in the camera and the client in the phone then the camera gets stuck in

```
socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
```

and the client returns an IOException in

```
mmSocket.connect();
```

> java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read
>   ret: -1

I guess it's something to do with the camera Bluetooth not accepting connections but I don't know that much about it and everything works fine when the roles are switched and the camera runs the client app.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "I guess it's something to do with the camera Bluetooth not accepting connections ". I pretty sure that's it. often device like that are designed to work in only one way (For example speakers act only as server, you ask from phone to connect to speaker, but a speaker can't ask a phone to connect to). Maybe it's written in your camera documentation

Comment: My problem here is that in my phone i can choose what device i want to connect to, but from the camera I can't (because i don't have a screen) so how can I make the connection? like Imagine i have 2 paired phones to the camera, how could I tell the camera which device to connect to?

Comment: That's what I was trying to point out in my comment. I think you just can't. And there's an implicit rule define in your camera that decide which phone to connect to. Possible rule are "accept first connection, and refuse all connections when I'm already connected", "accept all connections, so if I'm already connected, disconnect and accept new connection", etc.

Comment: Hmm Ok, thakns for your response :) I'll try to work around that

Comment: You can try some tests with mutiple phone, try to connect to the camera in different configurations, in order to guess the "accepting rule"

Comment: I tried with every device I have with no luck :/ I really don't know what else to try